# Whose content or which content

Tags: whose

"A pertinent way to analyze this broad phenomenon is to subdivide its analysis in three sections **which** content is partly based on the updated findings...".

Until this passage, I was 100% sure that in this case I had to use **whose** instead of which.

An entry on Merriam-Webster goes like this:
(Content)
a :  the matter dealt with in a field of study
… the **content of** sociology is inexhaustible … — Franklin H. Giddings

Comment: Agreed.  Or maybe "in which"

Comment: "...into three sections, the content of which...." Just out of curiosity, what "broad phenomenon" was being analyzed?

Comment: See this Google Ngram to compare frequency of usage: http://tinyurl.com/ychrj45b

Comment: Although academic writing likes extra words, I don't. You don't need *which content*: "subdivide its analysis in**to** three sections partly based on ..." Nod to @MarkHubbard.

Answer (score 2):

I think the cited context is a relatively uncommon literary / dated / formal / archaic construction as used [here...](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22the+which+desire+is+still%22)

> *The earliest people in the earliest ages, though they were rude and uncultivated, were eager to know the truth through study, **the which desire** is still, as we see, natural to every one.*

...where the article *(**the** which)* is normally included where there's a specific *noun* identified immediately after ***which***. In many such contexts you could do away with the noun (***content*** in OP's context, ***desire*** in mine) completely, but in both these examples that's a little problematic.

This is because the *exact* referent of ***which*** hasn't been precisely stated in preceding text *(which **content** = the division of the analysis into three sections, which **desire** = that of people eager to know the truth through study)*. The writer needs to insert a clarifying noun so it's obvious *which "which"* is being referred to.

It's not all that easy to find written examples of *[the] which **noun***, but [here's another one...](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22collar%20which%20rudeness%22)

> *the young buckramite rudely seized him by the collar; **which rudeness** he returned of course.*

Answer (score 1):

*Which* is an interrogative pronoun. In this form the sentence makes little sense since it looks like you are asking for something in the sentence (which content?). It can be used as a relative pronoun to refer to the precedents of the sentence. The precedent would be for instance the *three sections*

However, *whose* is the possessive case of *which* and *who*. Since the content belongs to the three sections and you want to make a reference to precedent sections, then you can use *whose* to form a more unambiguous and clear logical sentence.

Comment: Yes, that's my point, that's why I raised the question. This passage is not mine, I read it in a published paper.